# Copy constexpr array into class

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, constructor, constexpr

Suppose I have a class:

```
class MyClass{
  char array[12];
  public:
  MyClass(const char* arr) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++){
      array[x] = arr[x];
    }
  }
};
```

Is it possible to make the `MyClass` constructor `constexpr`.  The tricky part is initializing the new array....

Comment: May be some template trickery, reproducing the loop.

Comment: @DarthRubik - you're interested in a C++11 solution or in a C++14 solution?

Comment: @max66 C++11, because this is for a micro controller, which does not have access to a c++14 compiler (although a c++14 solution would be useful to people after me, so you could post that)

Comment: @DarthRubik - ok; other question: the argument of the constructor must be a `const char *` or can be a `char[12]` array?

Comment: @max66 I could be a `char[12]` array if it needed to be

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose (I hope) the following example could help.

I transformed your `MyClass` in a templated class where the template parameter is the dimension of the array (12); I hope isn't a problem.

Should work with C++11 and C++14

```
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t ...>
struct range
 { };

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ... Next>
struct rangeH 
 { using type = typename rangeH<N-1U, N-1U, Next ... >::type; };

template <std::size_t ... Next >
struct rangeH<0U, Next ... >
 { using type = range<Next ... >; };

template <std::size_t Dim>
class MyClass
 {
   public:
      char array[Dim];

      template <std::size_t ... rng>
         constexpr MyClass (const char arr[Dim], const range<rng...> &)
         : array{ arr[rng]... }
          { }

      constexpr MyClass (const char arr[Dim]) 
         : MyClass(arr, typename rangeH<Dim>::type())
          { }
 };


int main ()
 {
   constexpr MyClass<12> mc1("0123456789a");
   constexpr MyClass<37> mc2("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

   std::cout << mc1.array << std::endl;
   std::cout << mc2.array << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English

**--- edit: added C++14 example --**

If you (when you) can use C++14, you can use `std::index_sequence` and `std::make_index_sequence`, avoiding `range` and `rangeH`.

The example become

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t Dim>
class MyClass
 {
   public:
      char array[Dim];

      template <std::size_t ... rng>
         constexpr MyClass (const char arr[Dim],
                            const std::index_sequence<rng...> &)
         : array{ arr[rng]... }
          { }

      constexpr MyClass (const char arr[Dim]) 
         : MyClass(arr, std::make_index_sequence<Dim>())
          { }
 };


int main ()
 {
   MyClass<12> mc1("0123456789a");
   MyClass<37> mc2("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");

   std::cout << mc1.array << std::endl;
   std::cout << mc2.array << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

**-- addendum: how to avoid explicit dimension indication --**

If you find annoying count the char in a constant string, `auto` is your friend; if you declare a `constexpr` function in this way

```
template <std::size_t Dim>
constexpr MyClass<Dim> makeMyClass (const char (&arr)[Dim])
 { return MyClass<Dim> { arr }; }
```

you can declare your variables (or constants) of type `MyClass<N>` in this way

```
constexpr auto mc1 = makeMyClass("0123456789a");
constexpr auto mc2 = makeMyClass("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
```

instead

```
constexpr MyClass<12> mc1("0123456789a");
constexpr MyClass<37> mc2("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
```

Works with C++14 and C++11 too.

Comment: @DarthRubik - added a usefull (I hope) addendum

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `std::array` instead of a C-array and [everything just works](https://ideone.com/X0wUUE):

```
#include <array>

class MyClass{
  std::array<char, 12> array;
  public:
  constexpr MyClass(std::array<char, 12> arr) : array(arr){
  }
};
int main() {
    MyClass m({'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!'});
}
```

I don't know how to initialize the array with `"Hello World!"` instead of that list of characters.

Comment: I think you could use `std::experimental::to_array` to initialize it? If you don't have that, you can borrow the example implementation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/to_array

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that does not require you to specify the size before to use the class.

Note that this is a C++14 solution.
Anyway, you can easily find a C++11 implementation of the integer sequence stuff and adapt the solution to C++11.

Here is the code:

```
#include<functional>

class MyClass{
    const char arr[12];
    const std::size_t sz;

    template<std::size_t... I>
    constexpr
    MyClass(std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, I...>, const char *str)
        : arr{str[I]...}, sz{sizeof...(I)}
    { }

public:
    template<int N>
    constexpr
    MyClass(const char (&str)[N])
        : MyClass(std::make_index_sequence<N>(), str)
    { static_assert(N < 12, "!"); }

    constexpr std::size_t size() const { return sz; }
    constexpr char operator[](int n) const { return arr[n]; }
};

int main() {
    constexpr MyClass c{"foo"};
    static_assert(c.size() == 4, "!");
    static_assert(c[0] == 'f', "!");
    static_assert(c[1] == 'o', "!");
    static_assert(c[2] == 'o', "!");
    static_assert(c[3] == '\0', "!");
}
```

Template trickery, as mentioned in the comments, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have access to a c++14 compiler you can simply use a for-loop. However, the memory has to be initialized. A disadvantage is that the array is written twice, but that might be done while compiling. An advantage is that the code is a lot simpler.

```
struct array_wrapper{
    char array[11]{};
    constexpr array_wrapper(const char (& other)[11])   {
        for (unsigned j=0;j<sizeof(other)-1;j++){
            other[j]+=text[j];

        }
    }
};
```